# How to remove everything in a field after an newline or carriage return

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database table which occasionally contains fields in which the data is repeated with a newline or carriage rturn in between.

e.g.the field contains

```
John Smith
John Smith
```

Instead of just:

```
John Smith
```

I thought that some sort of regexp_replace, as below, would work to update the field and remove both the newline/CR and the text after it, but I can't get it to work.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET field =REGEXP_REPLACE(NAME, chr(13), '')
WHERE    ACCOUNT   = 123456
```

I expect the update to turn

```
John Smith
John Smith
```

into

```
John Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column , chr(13) || '.*$', '', 1, 0, 'n') 
WHERE ACCOUNT = 123456
```

Rationale :

- `chr(13) || '.*'` matches from the (first) new line to the end of string (greadily)
- the matching part of the string will be replaced by the empty string
- the final `'n'` option allows the dot character to match on newlines (by default it doesn't)

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24846c8cba670cc44787cc9aaba79897)**:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT 'John Smith' || chr(13) || 'John Smith' txt FROM DUAL)
SELECT 
    a.txt,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(a.txt, chr(13) || '.*', '', 1, 0, 'n') new_txt
FROM a;
```

```
TXT                   | NEW_TXT   
:-------------------- | :---------
John Smith            | John Smith 
John Smith            |
```

Note: as commented by [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole), if you want to match on both new line and carriage return, you can use :

```
'('||chr(13)||'|'||chr(10)||').*'
```

Comment: As the question says 'new line or carriage return' then I guess you could cover both with `'('||chr(13)||'|'||chr(10)||').*'`, but might be overkill.

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks, I added the regex to my answer as well.

Comment: To clarify, the REGEXP should look like this, to cover both:

REGEXP_REPLACE(a.txt, chr(13)||'|'||chr(10) || '.*$', '', 1, 0, 'n')

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET field = REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '^[^' || CHAR(13) || ']*')
    WHERE ACCOUNT = 123456;
```

Of course, this returns the *first line*.  If you want the last line:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET field = REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[^\n]*$')
    WHERE ACCOUNT = 123456;
```

Comment: The \ and n will be treated as separate single characters inside `[...]`, not as a newline character.